# showing continuity between two spaces (best approach)

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Context:

There is a normed space $(X, ||\cdot||)$.  There is a set of linearly independent vectors $v_1, v_2, ... v_n \in X$, which means that for any scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n$ we have $v = \alpha_1v_1 + \alpha_2v_2 + ... + \alpha_nv_n \in X$.

**Problem**:

Suppose a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$ is defined in the following way:

$f(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ..., \alpha_n) = ||\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2 + ... + \alpha_nx_n||$

**My attempt at a solution**:

Continuity of a map in this context would be the following.  For all tuples $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that whenever $||\alpha - \beta|| \leq \delta$, we have $|f(\alpha) - f(\beta)| \leq \epsilon$

Given $\epsilon >0$ I need to find a corresponding value $\delta$ such that the above inequality holds.  Here's what I have:

$|f(\alpha) - f(\beta)| = |||\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + ... + \beta_nx_n||- ||\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2 + ... + \alpha_nx_n|||$ by definition.

$\leq |||\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + ... + \beta_nx_n||| +  |||\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2 + ... + \alpha_nx_n|||$ by the triangle inequality.

After this step, I can apply the triangle inequality again, but I'm not exactly sure where to go from there.  Or, to be honest, whether this is even the right way to go about it in the first place.  Something tells me I could just let $\epsilon = \delta$ but again I don't know if this is correct.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What you wrote in the beginning is not what "linearly independent" means. And at some point the $v_i$-s disappear and some $x_i$-s appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property 
$$\left|\|x\|-\|y\|\right|\leq \|x-y\|$$

and with that,

$$|f(\alpha) - f(\beta)| = | ||\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + ... + \beta_nx_n||- ||\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2 + ... + \alpha_nx_n|| | \\ \leq  |\beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + ... + \beta_nx_n-(\alpha_1x_1 + \alpha_2x_2 + ... + \alpha_nx_n)| = \\
= |(\beta_1-\alpha_1)x_1+...+(\beta_n-\alpha_n)x_n| \leq \\ 
\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |\beta_i-\alpha_i||x_i| \leq \max |x_i| \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n|\beta_i-\alpha_i|= \max |x_i| \cdot \|\beta-\alpha\|_1$$

where the norm $1$ is defined as $\|z\|_1=|z_1|+\ldots+|z_n|$ for $z\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: can you remind me of the name of this inequality?

Comment: I don't think it has a name. At least not that I know of. Sorry. I can provide proof of it if you want it.

Comment: how would any other norm be related to the norm $1$?  It would be greater than it, no?

Comment: @Darthaml I've seen this inequality called the *reverse triangle inequality*.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are there any other ways to do this problem?

Comment: @Aweygan, thank you.  That's what I remembered but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Darthaml in $\mathbb R^n$ all norms are equivalent. That means that, for two norms $\|\cdot\|$ and $\|\cdot\|^*$ there are constants $A, B$ so that $$\|x\|\leq A\|x\|^*$$ and $$\|x\|^*\leq A\|x\|$$ so you can always *compare* two norms. That means that, in the end, it doesn't matter which norm you use.

Comment: @Darthaml I can think of another way, but it's essentially the same. The mapping $$f(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)=\sum_{i=1} \alpha_ix_i$$ is continuous, because is linear and $\mathbb R^n$ has finite dimension. Moreover, the norm mapping $$\|\cdot\| \to \mathbb R, x\mapsto \|x\|$$ is continuous, and that comes as a consequence of the *reverse triangle inequality*. Now the composition of continuous mappings is continuous, and so is your application, then.

Comment: The norm $$\|x\|=|x_1|+\frac12|x_2|+\frac13|x_3|+\cdots+\frac1n|x_n|$$ in $\mathbb R^n$ is actually smaller than $\|x\|_1$.